# Convert multipage tiff file to hdf5

Tags: python, numpy, shapes, hdf5, tiff

I would like to ask about conversion multipage tiff to h5 files.
I could get 2-d data array from the image, but I have 21GB multipaged tiff container, so I need to convert the images to 3-d data shape. And then, I want to put this data to hdf dataset.

Below is my code. Please help me to do this successfully.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import h5py
import tifffile
with tifffile.TiffFile('tomo.tif') as tif:
    num_frames = len(tif.pages)
    for n in range(num_frames):
        im = tif.pages[n].asarray()
        frame_shape = tif.pages[n].asarray().shape
        dtype = tif.pages[n].asarray().dtype
    with h5py.File('test.h5', 'w') as f:
        f.create_dataset('temp', data=im, shape=(n, *frame_shape))
    
print("array is of type:", type(im))
print("No. of dimensions", im.ndim)
print("Shape of array:", im.shape)
print("Size of array", im.size)
print("array stores elements of type", im.dtype)
print(im)
 -----------console message----------------
array is of type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
No. of dimensions 2
Shape of array: (2160, 2560)
Size of array 5529600
array stores elements of type uint16
[[1330 1380 1361 ... 1476 1606 1598]
 [1389 1440 1416 ... 1535 1549 1606]
 [1248 1367 1401 ... 1691 1525 1318]
 ...
 [1320 1379 1420 ... 1364 1585 1683]
 [1437 1387 1376 ... 1577 1563 1566]
 [1215 1326 1492 ... 1549 1626 1514]]

raise ValueError("Shape tuple is incompatible with data")
ValueError: Shape tuple is incompatible with data
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all pages in the TIFF file contain images of the same shape and data type, create an empty HDF5 dataset and copy all images from the TIFF to the dataset:

```
import h5py
import tifffile

with tifffile.TiffFile('tomo.tif') as tif:
    with h5py.File('test.h5', 'w') as f:
        dset = f.create_dataset(
            'temp', (len(tif.pages), *tif.pages[0].shape), tif.pages[0].dtype
        )
        for i, page in enumerate(tif.pages):
            dset[i] = page.asarray()
```

Comment: Could you check my below answer? Data shape is another issue on this code...Thanks for you help